# check parent when all its nodes are checked and check all nodes when their parent is checked throws error

Tags: vb.net, treeview, parent

I have tried this code:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterCheck(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterCheck
        Dim blnUncheck As Boolean = False
        Dim tn As TreeNode
        If e.Node.Nodes.Count = 0 Then
            For Each child As TreeNode In e.Node.Parent.Nodes
                If child.Checked = False Then
                    blnUncheck = True
                End If
            Next
            If blnUncheck = False Then
                e.Node.Parent.Checked = True
            Else
                e.Node.Parent.Checked = False
            End If (the code above is used to check parent when nodes are checked)
            Else (the code below is used to check nodes of parent when parent is checked)
                If e.Node.Checked = True Then
                        For Each tn In e.Node.Nodes
                            tn.Checked = True
                        Next
                    Else
                        For Each tn In e.Node.Nodes
                            tn.Checked = False
                        Next
                    End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

in order to: a) *check all nodes when their parent is checked*
             b) *check parent when all it's nodes are checked*

Although when when I remove one of two(a,b) from the code it works

When I combine them(as the code I have written), it throws a stackoverflow exception.
The code is used in treeview with checkboxes.

**EDIT: SOLVED**
Visit this link[TreeView.BeforeCheck Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforecheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for help (*read carefully*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try and step through your code you will see that every time you try and check/uncheck a node, you reenter the event.

Try adding this check:

```
If e.Action = TreeViewAction.Unknown Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If you havent manually clicked (EDIT: Also works for selecting by keypress) the node it will exit the event and stop the infinite loop

Comment: With a bit editing it worked thank's! I reference this link [TreeView.BeforeCheck Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforecheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for people who may need it in the future

Comment: Good stuff! That link is really useful!

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for that You can try ....

```
Private Sub CheckAllChildNodes(treeNode As TreeNode, nodeChecked As Boolean)
    Dim node As TreeNode
    For Each node In treeNode.Nodes
        node.Checked = nodeChecked
        If node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            Me.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked)
        End If
    Next node
End Sub


Private Sub node_AfterCheck(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterCheck
    If e.Action <> TreeViewAction.Unknown Then
        If e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            Me.CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked)
        Else
            e.Node.Parent.Checked = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```